# C - connect function - Invalid Argument error

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I am writing a C program to communicate between two processes through sockets and I am getting the following error with connect function call.

> connect:: Invalid argument

What am I missing in the call to connect ? 
Any help would be awesome !

This is my code -

```
void conn(char *hname)
{
    struct hostent *hp;
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    int port = 10000;
    int s, rc;

    hp = gethostbyname(hname);
    if ( hp == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "host not found (%s)\n", hname);
        exit(1);
    }

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if ( s < 0 ) {
        perror("socket:");
        exit(left);
    }

    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(port);
    memcpy(&sin.sin_addr, hp->h_addr_list[0], hp->h_length);

    rc = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
    if ( rc < 0 ) {
        perror("connect:");
        exit(rc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that all the errors you are getting? Try compiling with clang to get more details.

Comment: I took your code, added `char hname[] = "google.com"` and changed the port to `80`, and was successfully able to connect to google... This was done on Ubuntu Linux 14.04.

Comment: `struct sockaddr_in` has five fields. You're only filling three. I usually `memset` the whole mess to 0 before using it.

Answer (score 4):

`struct sockaddr_in` instances should be initialized to zero, e.g.,

```
struct sockaddr_in sin;
memset(&sin, '\0', sizeof(sin));
```

Which OS are you using? On linux, `EINVAL` is not a **documented** value for `errno` after a failed call to `connect(2)`, however, inspection of TCP and UDP source code in the linux kernel finds several cases where `EINVAL` gets returned, typically for invalid argument values.

Also, the first argument to `socket` is the protocol family.  Historically, on BSD, the constant you would use there would **`PF_INET`** rather than `AF_INET`.  In practice they were the same value and it appears that in at least RHEL 6 there really is only one constant any more.  But if you're on a BSD-ish system, you should probably use PF_INET.

Comment: I am getting an EINVAL after a failed call to `connect`, so I don't think that part of your answer is true. I'm using a Vagrant environment with Ubuntu.

Comment: you don't specify the version; in 16.04LTS, EINVAL is not a valid return value (https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man2/connect.2.html) nor in 18.04LTS nor in 19.10 (https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man2/connect.2.html).  However, current source for datagram (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1204c70d9dcba31164f78ad5d8c88c42335d51f8/net/ipv4/datagram.c) indicates `EINVAL` when indicated addr size < expected addr size, and for TCP (tcp_ipv4.c) there are other possible places that set err = -EINVAL.